# Change frequency of ticks matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, subplot, xticks

I am trying to lower the frequency of the xticks so that its more readable, but I am not able to do so when the x ticks are not integers.  Please see example below (matplotlib 2.1.1):

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax1 = f.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = f.add_subplot(212)

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [13,15,17,14,17,20,21]

ax1.plot(x, y, label="test1")
ax2.plot(x, y, label="test2")

ax2.set_xticks(ax2.get_xticks()[::2])

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This example works perfectly fine that the second graph now displays the x ticks every 2 tick.

When I change the x values to non integers like so

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax1 = f.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = f.add_subplot(212)

x = ["10:31","10:32","10:33","10:34","10:35","10:36","10:37"]
y = [13,15,17,14,17,20,21]

ax1.plot(x, y, label="test1")
ax2.plot(x, y, label="test2")

ax2.set_xticks(ax2.get_xticks()[::2])

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)
plt.show()
```

Then the graph is no longer accurate.  The spacing of the tick is now every 2, but it is still incrementing by 1 and is now not aligned correctly with the data.

[image]

Comment: I run your code and got the plot with ticks correctly aligned: [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz9Rj.png) (using matplotlib 3.4.2 and python 3.9.6)

Comment: hmm yea I am using matplotlib 2.1.1 and I cant currently update our environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is solved with a more recent version of matplotlib. Your code in matplotlib 3.4.2 works fine.

---

If you cannot update your environment, you should treat x axis format as datetime (tested with matplotlib 2.1.1).
In order to do this, first of all you have to convert x axis from `str` to `datetime`:

```
x_time = [datetime.strptime(x_i, '%H:%M') for x_i in x]
```

Then you plot your data replacing `x` with `x_time`:

```
ax2.plot(x_time, y, label="test2")
```

Now matplotlib knows your x axis is a datetime format. You still need to format properly ticks:

```
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(interval = 1))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

[`MinuteLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MinuteLocator) places ticks each `interval` value (1 minute in this case) and [`DateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) formats ticks in `'%H:%M'` format.
Finally you can set the space between each tick with:

```
ax2.set_xticks(ax2.get_xticks()[::2])
```

[image]

You could also avoid the last line and control space between ticks with `interval` parameter:

```
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(interval = 2))
```

[image]

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as md

f = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax1 = f.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = f.add_subplot(212)

x = ["10:31","10:32","10:33","10:34","10:35","10:36","10:37"]
y = [13,15,17,14,17,20,21]

x_time = [datetime.strptime(x_i, '%H:%M') for x_i in x]

ax1.plot(x, y, label="test1")
ax2.plot(x_time, y, label="test2")

ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(interval = 1))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

ax2.set_xticks(ax2.get_xticks()[::2])

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)
plt.show()
```